# Why does the vim-jedi popup have weird line wrapping?

Tags: wrapping, plugin-jedi-vim

When I'm nearing the right-hand side of my vim window, the vim-jedi's pop has some weird line-wrapping behavior:

[image: simple vim window with line-wrapped vim-jedi popup]

Is this normal behavior? How can I get the popup window to be shifted leftwards and appear all on one line?

Comment: Cannot reproduce with a simple `[lots of spaces] import assert [newline and a lot of spaces] assert.` (then completion starts). That was tested with the Konsole terminal emulator on KDE (Arch Linux), vim 7.4.738, jedi-vim 0.7.0-154-gbce599f.

Comment: did you noticed that your popup completion seems to be on two lines ? I see the `2, kwargs='hippos')` on the line below `(arg1, arg`.

Comment: @nobe4, yes. that's what I meant by "line wrapping".  I'm not sure it helps solve things though...

Comment: can you check your `textwidth` and your `wrap` options ?

Comment: Have you tried to debug your vimrc file [according to the steps here](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/51)? Perhaps there is a specific setting (or combination of a few settings) or another plugin that's causing this.

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  doing "set textwidth?" I get "textwidth=0" and doing "set wrap?" i get "wrap".  changing textwidth to 80 doesn't help.